# Why do we explicitly write super() and call super class constructor when compiler calls it for us in subclass?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Why do we explicitly write super() and call super class constructor. when compiler automatically adds super() as the first statement in subclass constructor?

Is this code

```
public class Sub extends Super {
   public Sub() {

   }
```

equivalent to this code?

```
public class Sub extends Super {
   public Sub() {
      super();
   }
```

Comment: we don't.  Maybe you do though.

Comment: Well, who is "we"? As for myself: I don't. And to be honest, I haven't seen anyone use a super-constructor without parameters so far...

Comment: That's totally optional, and depends on your company's coding standards

Comment: When I read your code, if the superclass constructor does any work, I like to be reminded by the explicit `super()` call that this is where the invocation of the super constructor happens. To me this would be the main reason: readability. As has already been said, it’s fairly opinion-based.

Comment: If you want to pass any arguments to a super constructor, you obviously need to do it via a `super(` _args_ `)` call

Comment: Yes, your two pieces of code will always behave the same.

Comment: You tickled my curiosity, so I did a rough count. In our codebase (thousands of classes), only between a quarter and a third of the Java files contain a super call (the rest either don’t declare a constructor or the constructor doesn’t call super explicitly). Out of the explicit calls to super, three quarters pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to call `super` if you are doing constructor overloading.
2. You need to use it if you are not using the default no arg constructor.

If you are using the default constructor and you are expecting it initialize based on a super class default constructor then there is no need to call `super`.

Comment: For item 1., my Java 8 happily calls the no-arg constructor in the superclass without an explicit `super()` even if both superclass and subclass have overloaded constructors. Maybe you meant that if the superclass does not have a no-arg constructor you need to call `super`.

Comment: You are right. In a typical scenario when your subclass overloads the constructor, you typically want to call a no-arg constructor.